# Can I programmatically expand a 'File' menu?

Tags: c#, menu

Often when we click the **File** menu in the menu bar it expands downwards as seen in this

[image]

How can I achieve this programmatically via C# code? I need to expand the file menu as if the file menu is clicked.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx

Comment: Is this a question about C#? Seriously, though, you only really need to put it in a tag (as you have done). You *shouldn't* use tags in question titles, and the tag is usually sufficient.

Comment: To find questions exclusive to C# you can use this link: [tag:C#] (or click somewhere where you see the C# tag). You can also include `[C#]` in a search using the search box (top right) to include only posts with that tag. For example: [`[C#] expand menu`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+expand+menu)

Answer (score 8):

Let's say the name of your MenuStrip is `fileMenu`, open it with:

```
fileMenu.ShowDropDown();
```

To show a SubMenuItem, open the ParentMenuItem and then the SubMenuStrip. Referring to your screenshot, I will name the SubMenuItem as "newMenuStrip".

```
fileMenu.ShowDropDown();
newMenuStrip.ShowDropDown();
```

When you try this, you will see no selection in the MenuStrips. So, this is your final code:

```
fileMenu.ShowDropDown();
newMenuStrip.ShowDropDown();
newMenuStrip.DropDownItems[0].Selected();
```

Comment: filemenu.showDropDown() works fine thanks but similarly how can i expand the 'Employees' submenu of my 'File'(mnuFile) as seen in this another screen shot (http://i524.photobucket.com/albums/cc327/manu308/mysubmenu_zpsf4bea69e.png)

Comment: To close a dropped down menu: `fileMenu.HideDropDown();`