# Is there a way to stop a Menu from closing when you click on it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We have a form in our program that allows a user to determine what a user can see when setting privileges, by using a menu bar. When a user clicks on an item, that item then is "selected" (gets a tick next to it). However, this also closes the menu.

[image]

Is there a way to stop this menu from closing (without affecting any other menu's in the program) when a user clicks on it? So far I have not found anything in the settings, and any `_click` methods are not affecting it either.

Comment: Maybe Ribbon menus can satisfy this need?

Comment: Winforms or WPF? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: you can expand it again. put some code in click events. how ever the effect may become like blink but you have to test it. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942327/can-i-programmatically-expand-a-file-menu

Answer (score 5):

Listen the [ToolStripDropDownClosingEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownclosingeventhandler?view=netframework-4.7.2) present in [ToolStripDropDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown?view=netframework-4.7.2). To do this just access the **ToolStripMenuItem.DropDown** Property, and so, add a listener that will handle the **Closing** event. We just need to check if the mouse pointer it's inside of toolStrip rectangle and this can be done with this piece of code:

```
private void ListenToolStripMenuItems(IEnumerable<ToolStripMenuItem> menuItems)
{
    // listen all menuItems
    foreach (ToolStrip menuItem in menuItems)
        menuItem.DropDown.Closing += OnToolStripDropDownClosing;
}

private void OnToolStripDropDownClosing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
{
        var tsdd = (ToolStripDropDown)sender;

        // checking if mouse cursor is inside
        Point p = tsdd.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);  
        if (tsdd.DisplayRectangle.Contains(p))
            e.Cancel = true;  // cancel closing
}
```

This way the AutoClose still working and the toolStrip will close properly.

Comment: This is a good solution, because it keeps the AutoClose functionality. Turning off AutoClose brings its own problems, in that you have to manually handle closing the menu again.

Comment: Thank You very much, the key was DropDown.Closing event

Answer (score 2):

I'm a hack, but I would do this for each item you can click:

```
 sampleNameToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown();
```

That way whenever you click something, it will also drop the menu down again right after.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The Items to be checked was a Level down in my case.

I solved it by adding a MouseEnter and MouseLeave Event to the ToolStripMenuItems that can be checked/unchecked.

In the MouseEnter I set AutoClose of both menuItems to false - in the MouseLeave I set it back to true.

[Visualization of the issue I had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA2b0.png)

```
 private void AddEventToToolStripMenuItems(IEnumerable<ToolStripMenuItem> menuItems)
        {
            // listen all menuItems
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
            {
                menuItem.MouseEnter += OnToolStripMouseEnter;
                menuItem.MouseLeave += OnToolStripMouseLeave;
            }
        }

       private void OnToolStripMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstLevelTooStipMenuItem.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
            secondLevelTooStipMenuItem.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
        }

        private void OnToolStripMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstLevelTooStipMenuItem.DropDown.AutoClose = true;
            secondLevelTooStipMenuItem.DropDown.AutoClose = true;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Get the `ToolStripMenuItem`
2. Get the `DropDown` from `ToolStripMenuItem`
3. Set `AutoClose` as `false`

Ref:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown(v=vs.110).aspx