# MenuItem AutoClose = false on dynamically generated Toolstrip Menu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstripdropdown

So, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034358/is-there-a-way-to-stop-a-menu-from-closing-when-you-click-on-it), I have been attempting to deal with a way to stop a drop down menu from closing when I click on an item.

In the linked question, one such answer suggested that I set the `AutoClose` property to false. I did so, and this did achieve what I asked. However, the way I implemented it means that the Drop Down menu is forced open.

**Form Code:**

```
public void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
    if (item != null)
        item.Checked = !item.Checked;

    item.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
}
```

I know why this is - the implementation means that there is no way to allow the `AutoClose` to be set to true. However, since the menuItems are dynamically generated in a different class, I don't have any events or objects to refer to.

This code copies the menu structure from the Main Form, and copies it across to recreate it in the "Profile View" (to set what users can/cannot see).

**Controller Code:**

```
private void PopulateProfileView(User_AccessProfilesView view, Menu_View mainMenu)
{
    // Disabled Items are not able to be set, becasue they are either always visible for every user,
    // or only visible to specific users (Administrator)
    List<string> disabledMenuItems = new List<string>();
    List<string> disabledSubMenuItems = new List<string>();

    bool error = false;          
    bool subError = false;
    _groupDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    // Populate the disallowed Menu Items from the Main Menu,
    // and then add the items specific to the Profile View
    disabledMenuItems.Add("File");
    disabledMenuItems.Add("Administrator");
    disabledMenuItems.Add("Help");
    disabledMenuItems.Add("Te&rminations");
    disabledMenuItems.AddRange(mainMenu.disallowedMenuItems);

    // Populate the disallowed Sub Menu Items from the Main Menu,
    // and then add the items specific to the Profile View
    disabledSubMenuItems.Add("View All");
    disabledSubMenuItems.AddRange(mainMenu.disallowedSubItems);

    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in mainMenu.mainMenuStrip.Items)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(item.Text);

        if (error == false)
        {
            // Add to the menu bar
            view.menuStrip.Items.Add(menuItem);
            menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(view.ToolStripMenuItem_Click);

            foreach (ToolStripItem dropItem in item.DropDownItems)
            {
                if (dropItem is ToolStripMenuItem)
                {
                    ToolStripMenuItem menuDropItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(dropItem.Text);

                    // Same concerns as above with regards to doing a substring check
                    // to decide if menu items should be excluded or not.
                    foreach (string s1 in disabledSubMenuItems)
                    {
                        if (!menuDropItem.Text.Contains(s1))
                        {
                            subError = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            subError = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!subError)
                    {
                        menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(menuDropItem);
                        menuDropItem.Click += new EventHandler(view.ToolStripMenuItem_Click);
                    }
                }
                else if (dropItem is ToolStripSeparator)
                { menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripSeparator()); }
            }
```

How do I implement the `AutoClose` property correctly so that if I click on a menu item, the menu won't close, but if I click on the menu header, or move the mouse away from the menu, or select another menu (either by click or mouse over), the menu does Close?

---

Apologies if this is a simple issue - I have been out of the game for roughly a year, and have to jump back into this and I am having a little bit of an issue following everything properly.

Comment: A menu that doesn't close on a click is a toolbar.  You have one in the toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem you can follow these steps:

1. You should determine which menu items should keep open even after clicking on them. I'll use "keepopen" as value of `Tag` property for those items that should be kept open after clicking.
2. For the menu item which contains those items, you need to get `DropDown` property and and handle its `ItemClicked` event and in the `ItemClicked` event, you should check if the item which is clicked is one of those `"keepopen"` items, then set `DropDown.AutoClose` of the container menu item to `false`. For other items, set it to `true`. It will prevent closing those `"keepopen"` item when clicking, while let other items close by click.
3. You should handle `CheckedChanged` event of those `"keepopen"` items and set `DropDown.AutoClose` to `true`. While using the `Click` event handler we prevented the items from closing, here we enable the closing again, so if the user click outside of the menu, it will close.

Then this would be the result, look at mouse clicks:

[image]

**Example**

As an example, create an empty form and handle its `Load` event and use following code. When you click on `SubMenu1`, `SubMenu2` or `SubMenu3`, they will just get checked or unchecked without closing the menu. But of you click outside the menu or on `SubMenu4`, it will close the menu.

```
const string keepopen = "keepopen";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuStrip = new MenuStrip() { Dock = DockStyle.Top };
    this.Controls.Add(menuStrip);
    var menu1 = (ToolStripMenuItem)menuStrip.Items.Add("Menu1");
    menu1.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Submenu1")
    { Tag = keepopen, CheckOnClick = true });
    menu1.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Submenu2")
    { Tag = keepopen, CheckOnClick = true });
    menu1.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Submenu3")
    { Tag = keepopen, CheckOnClick = true });
    menu1.DropDownItems.Add("-");
    menu1.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Submenu4"));
    menu1.DropDown.ItemClicked += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.ClickedItem.Tag == keepopen)
            menu1.DropDown.AutoClose = false;
        else
            menu1.DropDown.AutoClose = true;
    };
    menu1.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
        .Where(x => x.Tag == keepopen)
        .ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.CheckedChanged += (obj, args) =>
            {
                menu1.DropDown.AutoClose = true;
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem in applying the solution.